# A bounded Lebesgue measurable function and integral.

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, almost-everywhere

I honestly have no idea where to even begin with this question:

> Let $f: [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be bounded and Lebesgue measurable. Suppose that for every $0\leq a<b\leq 1$, we have
>
> $$ \int_a^b f(x)\ \mathsf dx=0. $$
>
> Prove that $f=0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Could you prove the contrapositive statement?

Comment: It follows from [Lebesgue differentiation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem)

Answer (score 1):

Denote
$$F(t) = \int_0^t f(x)\,dx \quad 0\le t\le 1.$$

From the condition $F(t)=0$ for any $t\in[0,1]$. Since [$F'(t)=f(t)$ a. e.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem), then $f(t) = 0$ a. e.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG $f$ is borel measurable, otherwise replace $f$ with a borel measurable function that equals $f$ almost everywhere. The hypotheses state that $\int f 1_A = 0$ for all intervals $A$. Note that these intervals form a $\pi$-system that generate the borel $\sigma$-algebra. Consider the set of functions for which $\int f g = 0$. It is clearly a vector space, contains the  constant function $1$, and if $g_n$ increases to a bounded $g$, then by dominated convergence $\int f g_n \to \int fg$. It follows by the monotone class theorem that $\int f g = 0$ for all bounded borel measurable $g$. Take $g=f$ to conclude that $f=0$ a.e.